# Check Multiple boolean condition using dword in c++

Tags: c++, enums, dword

I am really new to using `DWORD` in C++ in place of boolean. Hence, please excuse my question.

I have an `enum`:

```
enum foo
{
  foo1 = 0x0;
  foo2 = 0x1
  //....
}
DWORD foo;
```

I am using this `enum` to check for multiple conditions:

```
if(somethinghappenstothisvariable)
{
  foo|= foo1;
}

if(somethinghappenstosecondvariable)
{
 foo|=foo2;
}
```

Now in another file I have to check for individual variables condition

```
if(foo &foo1)
{
  //do something;
}

if(foo & foo2)
{
 //do something;
}
```

I figured that `|=` adds up the value to the `DWORD` if both conditions are `true` which leads to `foo & foo2` only to be true while `foo & foo1` will not be as the value of `DWORD` will be `1`. Hence, I was wondering if there is anyway I can check this for individual `DWORD` value.

Comment: foo|= foo1; ==> foo|= 0 == foo, and foo & foo1  == foo & 0 ==> 0, I guess you want foo1 = 0x1(2^0), foo2 = 0x2(2^1), foo3 = 0x4(2^2)...

Comment: yup, foo1 is zero in your current implementation. The lowest actual bit is value "1" not "0". "0" matches no bits. Each bit value needs to be double the one before as well.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Note that if `foo1`, `foo2`, and so on are bitshift indicators (i.e. used as `foo |= 1 << foo1` instead of `foo |= foo1`), then `foo1` should be `0`.  I believe I've seen both versions used; I personally prefer the former, where `fooN` is the bit's value instead of its number, because it's easier to define & use "clear all" and "set all" flags.  [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17e731bdc91efe02) a simple example of what I mean.

Comment: Using `foo` for both the enum type and the variable name is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The issue: 1 = bit 0, 0 is invalid.
To the check each "condition" should represent a separate bit (bit 0 = 1, bit 1 = 2, etc.)

So - a simple change: `foo1 = 0x01; foo2 = 0x02;` should fix it.
NOTE: any additional checks should represent bit values, NOT ordinal.
In other words, `foo3 = 0x04;` (not `0x03;`)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it correct easier by creating these constants with shifts:

```
enum foo
{
  foo1 = 1 << 0;
  foo2 = 1 << 1;
  foo3 = 1 << 2;
  //....
}
```

This way you can be sure that each mask has a single bit set.